# User Process and Kernel Process

Tags: process, virtual-memory

Actually, I am new to operating systems and linux.

According to my university resources, all software in the computer divides into two different types of process which are `user processes` and `system processes`. All things up to now sound senseful.

These resources also says these things with the help of some images :

"The user processes have virtual memory range. For example, memory range of the process A is from A12B to A15B. However, the process A sees its memory range as from 0000 to 0030. It is not allowed to see or access memory spaces out of its space."

This also sounds me senseful, but there is no knowledge about the system processes and their memory range in the sources. Can anyone explain me memory range of system processes ?